# Problems with improper vhosts configuration on Apache 2 / Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have various subdomains set up successfully as virtual hosts on my Digital Ocean Droplet. For some reason though, my latest subdomain is serving a different subdomain, and I'm not sure why. So if you go to `selingo.mikeheavers.com` it services the contents of `exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com`. Furthermore, if you just enter my droplet's IP address, it serves `exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com` - I would expect it to just serve `mikeheavers.com`. What have I mixed up?

I set both subdomains up through a .conf file and `sudo a2ensite [file.com.conf]`

This is the contents of selingo.mikeheavers.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        ServerAdmin mheavers@gmail.com
        ServerName selingo.mikeheavers.com
        ServerAlias www.selingo.mikeheavers.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/selingo/public_html


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =selingo.mikeheavers.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is exhibitcolumbus.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ServerName exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com
        ServerAlias www.exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/exhibitcolumbus/public_html


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I also noticed this in my `/etc/hosts` file, and I'm not sure where the first entry came from - I don't remember setting it up:

```
127.0.1.1 extra extra
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

I'm also using letsencrypt for SSL, so possible that is causing issues? I saw that it created some conf files as well, but they are basically the same as above, with the addition of:

```
SLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com/chain.pem
```

I also set up A Records for each subdomain on my droplet which point to my IP address (http://107.170.120.88/), which is weirdly also not serving up my primary domain (should be what you see at mikeheavers.com)

I see this when I enter `apachectl -S`:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html] does not exist
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com
         port 443 namevhost mikeheavers.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mikeheavers.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost prototypes.mikeheavers.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prototypes.mikeheavers.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com
         port 80 namevhost mosaic.mikeheavers.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mosaic.mikeheavers.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost prototypes.mikeheavers.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prototypes.mikeheavers.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost selingo.mikeheavers.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/selingo.mikeheavers.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.selingo.mikeheavers.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
```

How do I untangle whatever mess I made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created a virtual host to serve https://selingo.mikeheavers.com/. Thus when this URL is accessed, Apache chooses the default virtual host, which according to your listing is `default server exhibitcolumbus.mikeheavers.com`.

You just need to create a new virtual host to serve this site.

Comment: I did create a vhost - or at least I think I did: I made a copy of my 000-default.conf called selingo.mikeheavers.com.conf, I added the contents (shown above), I did an `a2ensite` for the conf file, and I created an A record in Digital Ocean. That's all I normally do.

Comment: @mheavers You have one that serves http on port 80. You don't have one that serves https on port 443.

Comment: I guess I'm confused how I would set one up for that port, or why it is even looking at :443

Comment: @mheavers Because you redirected everything to https. And you can set it up like all the others you already set up.

Comment: Agh! Thank you...Just needed to run letsencrypt again.